# Enabing IIS using CAQuietExec64 in Wix installer does not work

Tags: iis, wix, installation, silent-installer

I need to make a windows installer which enables (installs) IIS on windows.
When I run the .msi file, it runs without any give any however, IIS does not get enabled(installed) when I go to Program and Features/Turn Windows Feature on off, it does not get installed

Here is my wxs file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Id="*" Name="IISInstaller" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Company" UpgradeCode="21ece05f-bf5c-4f97-850e-cb7cef2bf65e">
        <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
        <MediaTemplate />

    <Property Id="QtExec64CmdLine" Value='"[WindowsFolder]Sysnative\dism.exe" /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:IIS-ApplicationDevelopment /FeatureName:IIS-WebServer 
              /FeatureName:IIS-WebServerRole /FeatureName:IIS-RequestFiltering /FeatureName:IIS-Security 
              /FeatureName:IIS-NetFxExtensibility /FeatureName:IIS-ASPNET /FeatureName:IIS-ISAPIExtensions 
              /FeatureName:IIS-ISAPIFilter /FeatureName:IIS-DefaultDocument /FeatureName:IIS-HttpErrors /FeatureName:IIS-StaticContent 
              /FeatureName:IIS-HttpLogging /FeatureName:IIS-RequestMonitor /FeatureName:IIS-HttpCompressionStatic 
              /FeatureName:IIS-HttpCompressionDynamic /FeatureName:IIS-RequestFiltering /FeatureName:IIS-WindowsAuthentication'/>

    <CustomAction Id="SilentLaunch" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec64" Execute="immediate" Return="check" />        
    </Product>  
</Wix>
```

even when I change the value in the property to run a simple command to make directory

```
mkdir test
```

it does not work either.

Could you please help me what is the problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Two potential problems:

1. You have declared the custom action but you haven't put it in a sequence by declaring where it's going to run and what conditions apply. So it didn't run.

Step 2 is missing: http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixdev/extensions/authoring_custom_actions.html

2. After you've done that, the custom action is marked immediate which is usually an error because changes to the system should be done in deferred mode, and immediate custom actions don't run elevated.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added the InstallExecuteSequence as you mentioned. And also set the customAction in deferred mode and Impersonate as no. I also run it in command line msiexec /i installer.msi /L*V "package.log". it does not work either. The only error in the log was "Installation success or error status: 1603" which a link on microsoft support says that SYSTEM role does not have full control which is not the case.

Comment: I'd post a new question for that - 1603 is nearly always a custom action failure, and the log should say if it's the one related to IIS or something else.